# Trouble loading png image URL into ImageView using Glide or Picasso

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, picasso, android-glide

I am having a strange issue attempting to load an image URL into an image view.

The image is a png. When loading the image from the drawable folder, the following works fine:

```
backdrop = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backdrop);
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.nike_shoes.png).into(backdrop);
```

However, the following, for some reason does not work at all. I tried Glide and Picasso:

```
backdrop = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backdrop);
String url = "http://41.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lpzremYbtp1qeto98o1_1280.png";
Glide.with(this).load(url).into(backdrop);
```

The image view XML looks like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the answer. I simply needed to add the following permission into the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```